# Visual Studio Template - How DO I Copy a .gitignore file to the root folder where the .sln file exists?

Tags: visual-studio-templates

I have created a multi project visual studio template .vstemplate file. It creates 3 projects and the folders look like this in windows explorer:

```
Project1
Project2
Project3
Project.sln
```

I want to include and copy a .gitignore file to the root directory where the .sln file is located. How can I perform this task using the vstemplate xml syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using the traditional visual studio template approach. I found a newer way to do this using the dotnet new template approach. This gives you much more flexibility and is a newer approach to project templates. Check out the documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/custom-templates